# jQuery on click not working on iPhone (touch devices)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, iphone

Can anyone please explain to me why this is working in the browser but not on mobile devices like Apple's iPhone. On iPhone, I never get the `hello` from the alert. Why?

```
<div class="close">
  Click here
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).on('click', '.close', function() {
  alert('hello');
});
```

Example here: https://jsfiddle.net/27ezjrqr/5/

Answer (score 41, accepted):

By default, divs are not a "clickable" elements. But adding `cursor: pointer;` makes iOS treat it as clickable.

So all you need to do is add

```
.close {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

to your CSS and then it will work.

Proof here: https://jsfiddle.net/27ezjrqr/6/

```js
$(document).on('click', '.close', function() {
  alert('hello');
});
```

```css
.close {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="close">
  Click here
</div>
```

Comment: I don't believe it, but you are correct! Thank you, that does work indeed!

Comment: Well I would still like to know why this strange behaviour is. So I'll wait a bit and accept sooner or later if no other answer will occur...

Comment: As far as I understand it, by default, divs are not a "clickable" element so iOS doesn't treat them as such. Adding the cursor / pointer makes them a clickable item.

Comment: thank you for the update! Now this is so easy to understand and considered it this way it does make sense! Tahnk you

Comment: this is great, you saved our two days of efforts with this.

Answer (score 1):

I used the touchstart event with the click , it did the job for me

```
 $(document).on("click touchstart tap", "#button_X", function (){
//your code here      
 });
```

Comment: You say the same as @dannyjolie almost 2 years ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35945970/jquery-on-click-not-working-on-iphone/35946223#35946223 . Also be careful with using `touchstart and tap` as the function then could fire twice ...

Comment: Also be careful using touchstart as it will fire even if user is scrolling (as opposed to intentionally clicking).

Answer (score 0):

The Javascript `alert()` and more bugs are fixed as of iOS 7.0.3.

Comment: Hi acardoso, thank you for your answer. Why does this https://jsfiddle.net/vvsq2gw1/ work on iPhone and the example in the question does not?

Comment: I am guessing there is something to do with the click event.

Answer (score 0):

Click events don't work like expected on iOS. You can use something like touchstart instead, or use a weird iOS quirk: in your CSS, set `.close{cursor:pointer}`.